# Django-nonrel on Google App Engine API creation

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm developing an app that interfaces with an iPhone app via an API. I am building it on Google App Engine, using django-nonrel. I'm looking for a solution that allows me to build read-write APIs that perform CRUD operations.

I've tried django-tastypie, but it doesn't work with django-nonrel.

The biggest restriction of django-nonrel is no JOINs.

What is the best way to write those APIs? Should I just write the views from scratch, or is there some library that I could use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I got tastypie working, with two small code changes.  It was pretty simple.

See here: http://eatdev.tumblr.com/post/12076483835/tastypie-on-django-nonrel-on-app-engine